# Can't find my error

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, perl

Hi here is a small snipit of a very large perl program I am working on, however I believe the error is around this part.

```
my $headd = "test,test1,test2,test3,ect";
my @headers = split(',', $headd);

CONNECT TO DATABASE STUFF THAT WORKS FINE

 my %column_mapping = (
    "GPS ALT" => 'GPS_ALT',
    "GPS DTS" => 'GPS_DTS',
    "GPS FIX" => 'GPS_FIX',
    "GPS HDG" => 'GPS_HDG'
 )

my $sql       = sprintf 'INSERT INTO tablename ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )',
   join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} } @$headers ),
   join( ',', ('?') x scalar @$headers );   # note the list around the '?'
```

Since I am fairly new to perl, if I had to guess I would say its around here

```
    join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} } @$headers ),
    join( ',', ('?') x scalar @$headers );
```

I think I have the wrong data types for headers or something, but I am not entirely sure what the problem is, it just crashes around those lines.

If you happen to see something I did wrong that would be great:)

Comment: Do you have `use strict;` enabled? If so, you should be getting `Global symbol "$headers" requires explicit package name` because you declare the array `@headers` at the top but never declare the array reference `$headers` that you try to use in `map { ... } @$headers`.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes I do have it enabled, and I get that. I was not sure how to use the map {...}@$headers proper. Am I missing a declaration line or using the map wrong?

Comment: Change `@$headers` to `@headers`. `@headers` is an array; `@$headers` dereferences the array *reference* `$headers`, which you never declared.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to tell us what the problem is. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @DaveCross Originally it was what described. Since I have changed (at)$headers to (at)headers, the problem is saying I have an initialized value in the join. Which I find weird when I decalre it upfront.

Comment: A vital tool in the programmer's skillset is **accuracy**. I suspect you mean "uninitialized" rather than "initialized". Please be more careful in reporting what you see, or we won't be able to help you. If you have an uninitialised value coming out of your `map`, then I expect that `$headd` contains values that don't exist as keys in `%column_mapping`.

Comment: @DaveCross this was exactly it, thank you very much. Sorry for writing the wrong problem in my last comment.

Comment: I've written that all up as an answer. Feel free to accept it :-)

Comment: @DaveCross accepted and voted up, I feel like an idiot for not realizing I wasn't doing the mapping proper. Would have taken me a long while to clue in that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is in not adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your Perl code. These lines will find a number of problems that often sneak into Perl programs. They would have found this problem.

The problem is that you declare an array called `@headers`.

```
my @headers = split(',', $headd);
```

But the next time you try to use it, you are assuming that it is an array **reference** called `$headers`.

```
join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} } @$headers )
```

In Perl, `$headers` and `@headers` are two completely different variables with absolutely no connection between them. As you have never given `$headers` a value, trying to dereference it (`@$headers`) was never going to go well.

But you've worked that out from the comments. You've made the suggested fix (replace `@$headers` with `@headers`) and now you get a different error:

> the problem is saying I have an initialized value in the join

I assume you mean "uninitialized" :-)

Sounds like the problem is on the same line that we discussed above (now with the fixed syntax):

```
join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} } @headers )
```

So what's happening here? Well, we are effectively translating values to new values. For each value in `@headers` we look it up in `%column_mappings` and return the associated value from the hash.

How could that give us an undefined value? Well, what happens if we look up a key in a hash that doesn't actually exist in the hash? Perl gives us the special value "undef". Which would trigger the warning that you are getting.

So my suggestion to you is that you double-check the values that you are getting in `@headers` (which will be the values from `$headd`) and make sure that all of those possible values have an associated key in `%column_mappings`.

One workaround would be to set a default value in the `map`. Something like this perhaps:

```
join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} // 'MISSING MAPPING' } @$headers )
```

That will almost certainly break your database interaction at some point further down the line - but at least it will be obvious what the problem is!

**Update:** To eliminate the problematic values before they get into `@headers`:

```
my @headers = grep { exists $column_mapping{$_} } split(',', $headd);
```

You'll want to move this statement after the definition of `%column_mappings` (for hopefully obvious reasons).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way that instead of a default value. Either remove from the string before its made into an array, remove from the array, or not do a join on it, if its not in the map.